# How to get all computer names on Ad-Hoc Network in VB 6?

Tags: vb6

I have a combobox and command button on my form.  How do I populate the combobox with all of the computer names connected to an ad-hoc network?

Comment: What kind of network? A Windows network with NetBIOS enabled? Something else?

Comment: An Ad-hoc network, using Windows 7.

Comment: As if you were to go to Start >> Control Panel >> Networks >> Create new network >> Ad-hoc, then on the other computer "Connect to network".

Comment: So basically, no router or internet connection, but two Windows 7 PC's on a wireless PC to PC "ad-hoc" network.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there is no easy way of doing this.  The API is documented at the following URL:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706584(v=VS.85).aspx

The documentation root for wireless networking is at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706556(v=VS.85).aspx

It says that the documentation is for C/C++ programmers.  It will take a lot of COM knowledge to create code in VB that can interface with it.

The only other way I can suggest is find a command-line utility which outputs this information, and parse its ouput.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a very long while since I did anything with VB6, but I can remember enumerating LAN computers went something like [this.](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/3169/list-network-computers/)

Answer (score 0):

wow, it sure is very tedious in **VB**, but you can also get all computer names on your **ad-hoc network** or any form of network using the **command prompt**.
with:

`net view /all`

so in order to get the names into your vb application you can pipe the output of the command above into a textFile with:

```
net view /all >>names.txt
```

in **VB** that will be

```
shell("net view /all >> names.txt")
```

then read in the text file using **VB**